# SwiftUI CoreData crashes preview

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I have the following code to draw a list of cars, data stored in coredata.

However the swiftui preview seems to break when I add the line of code that fetches data from the databases.

the error logs tells the following:

> PotentialCrashError: test app.app may have crashed
>
> mileage app.app may have crashed. Check
>   ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports for any crash logs from your
>   application.
>
> ==================================
>
> |  Error Domain=com.apple.dt.ultraviolet.service Code=12 "Rendering
>   service was interrupted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Rendering
>   service was interrupted}

this is the code the part where foreach starts and ends causes the error:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CarListView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Car.all()) var cars: FetchedResults<Car>

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                List {
                    Section(header: Text("Cars")) {
                        ForEach(self.cars, id: \.numberPlate) { car in
                            HStack {
                                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                    Text(car.name)
                                    Text(car.numberPlate)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

struct CarListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CarListView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to the fact it couldn't somehow get a context which allows to fetch the data in preview mode. By manually doing so for preview mode it fixes the issue.

```
struct CarListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        return CarListView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else was wondering, this crashed because when simulating a preview for a specific view, it doesn't have contextual information that is provided by the base system environment: in this case, the managedObjectContext. So, it will crash because he's referencing an object provided by the environment. By providing a static version of the object (viewContext: ManagedObjectContext), it allows the preview to load and assert any needed context.

For most newer applications the following will also work:

```
struct CarListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
let persistentController = PersistentController.preview
CarListView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistentController.container.viewContext)
}
}
```

Comment: You should use `PersistentController.preview` vs `PersistentController.shared`

Comment: Yes, that's true. PersistentController.preview allows you to have CoreData in memory and separate what's for testing and what's not.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your preview environment is set up correctly.

```
struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```